# Enable/Disable Chrome global commands

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Looking through the API docs I think that the answer to this is no, but is there any way to toggle support for Chrome commands from inside an extension?

The problem: When using global commands Chrome will hijack that hotkey so other applications that are listening for that key will never get it. For example, I have an extension that uses the media keys. Many desktop applications (itunes, etc.) use the media keys as hotkeys as well. When the extension commands are set to use the media keys globally, Chrome is the only application that receives those key presses.

There is a [bug report here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396991) about this problem, but no work has been done on it yet.

From an extension perspective, the best solution with the current implementation would be a button inside the extension's browser action that could toggle Chrome listening for commands (which would in turn free up the keys that it is listening for). Is anything like this possible?

The best that I have come up with is a button inside the browser action to actually disable the extension (using [management.setEnabled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled)). The problem with this approach is that the user will then have to navigate to chrome://extensions to re-enable it - far from ideal.

I have been recommending to my users to change the hotkeys to something else if they are encountering this problem, but that is also not a great solution.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you can do much better about this issue nowadays. What the way I suggest is just tell the users to adjust the Chrome's hotkey. To see reference on this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/stop-chrome-hijacking-media-keys-heres/

Comment: Any news on this in 2018?

Comment: Go to chrome://extensions and remove the Google Play Music extension. It listens for the media keys and hijacks external usage of said media keys if using an external app.